# Workflow for users to download files?

Tags: gallery

I am running v3.2.1 with the Boldy theme.
I have installed the Wordpress [Download Monitor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-monitor/) plugin to create a [downloads gallery](http://www.dekho.com.au/download-gallery/).

[I asked for some assistance before](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26008/best-practise-for-securing-files-in-a-download-gallery) on a good workflow for allowing our clients to download files from our wordpress site.
- I may need to better re=phrase that Q.

**Workflow:**
- Create a guest account (subscriber)
- Upload the product (zip) and add it to the gallery.
- Make use of the 'Member Only file' tickbox, so that anyone not logged in wont be able to get file.
- send an email out to our paying customers with credentials for guest account

That aside, the workflow has been rejected by our marketing team as its not a smooth process for end-users:

**Problem:**
- Email has link to login ([wp-admin](http://www.dekho.com.au/wordpress/wp-admin/))
- After logging in, they get re-directed to the wordpress dashboard.
- They then have to navigate to the dl gallery and find the links to the download.

If you [try and download](http://www.dekho.com.au/download-gallery/?did=13) the product when your not logged in, it will tell you:

> You must be logged in to download this file.  ← Back to Dekho Resource
>   Center

Ideally there would be a looping re-direct to let you login and then download zip?

Looking for an answer that gives my users a slick way to download without getting lost along the way and minimising clicks.

Comment: I honestly don't believe this is an appropriate use of WP - WP simply doesn't match this kind of functionality.

Comment: WP can certainly handle redirects. The process described is absolutely possible. That being said, you can edit questions though. Please do not post duplicates if the first one's answers are not satisfactory. Consider a [bounty](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) instead. Be so kind as to delete one of the questions.

Comment: deleted other Q

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your theme's functions.php file

```
function Get_curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
        $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}


add_filter('gettext','custom_login_to_download_msg');

function custom_login_to_download_msg( $input ) {
    
    if( !is_admin() && 'You must be logged in to download this file. <br/><br/><a href="%1$s"><strong>?† Back to %2$s</strong></a>' == $input  )
        return 'You must be logged in to download this file. <br/><br/>
            <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(Get_curPageURL()); ?>" title="Login"><Strong>Login To Download</Strong></a><br/><br/>
            <a href="%1$s"><strong>?† Back to %2$s</strong></a>';

    return $input;
}
```

Which should give you :

[image]

And the **Login to Download** Link will start the download automatically once they are logged in.

Comment: Looks promising, but still the client will login, and still have to navigate back to the download page (i.e. click out of the dashboard once logged in) right?

Comment: Nope,  the user will be redirected automatically after the login to the download page.

Comment: u da man!  Let me implement over weekend, and ill report back...